# getting error in mysql-- #1064 error while creating trigger

Tags: mysql, database, sql

I need to create a trigger for a table called try.. which will execute after something is entered into the table..(I am using phpmyadmin mysql)
But i am getting `#1064` error while creating it..
My trigger contains

```
BEGIN
DECLARE aa decimal(4,3);
DECLARE bb decimal(4,3);
DECLARE cc decimal(4,3);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT a,b,c FROM site;
OPEN cur1
FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 into aa,bb,cc;
WHILE FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
PRINT aa
END
END
```

it shows an error like this

```
 MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 
into aa,bb,cc; WHILE FETCH_STATUS=0 BEGIN PRINT aa END ' at line 7
```

I am a newbie to trigger..Help me... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your inconsistent use of the semi-colon to delimit your commands would be (at least part of) your problem.  You need one at the end of each command.  :)

`Open cur1` is a stand-alone command that should have a `;` after it (as should your "Print" statement).

Since it doesn't, then MySQL will interpret the two lines as a single command: `OPEN cur1 FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 into aa,bb,cc;` which is an invalid command.

Edit after comment:

As the error you reported says, you have syntax errors.  It's (still) due to improper semi-colon usage, but you also have errors in your While statement usage.  A `While` loop should have a `do`, and be ended with `End While` (no additional Begin/End block required).

Check out the MySQL Help: [13.6.5.8 WHILE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html).

Try this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE aa decimal(4,3);
    DECLARE bb decimal(4,3);
    DECLARE cc decimal(4,3);
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT a,b,c FROM site;
    OPEN cur1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur1 into aa,bb,cc;
    WHILE FETCH_STATUS=0 DO
        PRINT aa;
    END WHILE;
END;
```

Comment: changed that.. but now getting error as 
`MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN PRINT aa; END END' at line 9`

Comment: as I said, it's your inconsistent semi-colon usage.  "END" is the end of a command, and should therefore have a semicolon after it to terminate the statement/command. I'll update my answer.